# Cannot use child input value in parent's [ngClass] logic

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, eventemitter

I am attempting to pass the user input value from my `input` through to the parent and use this value to determine which row to highlight within my `<li *ngFor...` element.

I can actually pass the value through successfully so it seems, as I have set up a `console.log` to catch what is first emitted by the child component and then also what is caught by the parent, but I just cannot get it to be seen by my `[ngClass]` logic section...

The logic does work correctly if I hardcode the value of the row I wish to highlight in, but of course, I want to do this programatically.

**parent.component.ts**

```
  rowId: number;

  childToParent(val){
    console.log('received from child: ' + val);
    this.rowId = val;
  }
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<app-child (childToParent)="childToParent($event)"></app-child>
<li *ngFor="let item of items" attr.id="item-{{item.id}}" [ngClass]="{'active': item.id === rowId}">
  <div class="item">
   ...
</li>
```

**child.component.ts**

```
@Output() childToParent = new EventEmitter<String>();

  sendToParent(id){
    console.log('sending to parent: ' + id)

    this.childToParent.emit(id);
  }
```

**child.component.html**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="val" (input)="sendToParent(val)"/>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-parent-child-interaction)

Comment: Everything seems fine except your `rowId`. What is your `rowId`? Is it really numeric from your child component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are you sure item.id and rowId both are number type? you can change "===" into "==" and it will work for both string and number.

Comment: Aha! You are correct. Copy/Paste error. I had it sent to `EventEmitter<string>` and then hadn't explicitly stated `type="number"` on the input. A second pair of eyes comes in handy at times :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just parseInt val

```
this.rowId = parseInt(val, 10);
```